# Import Adobe Illustrator bezier coordinates into Processing bezier() function

Tags: import, processing, bezier, adobe-illustrator, p5.js

I'm working on a project where I can take my lettering pieces I do on illustrator with the pen tool and take the bezier point coordinates (curves and all) into processing [bezier()](https://processing.org/reference/bezier_.html) function so I can individually manipulate the points with different formulas for animation.

[image: Lettering piece done with pen tool]

I've tried using [Adobe Point Exporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/illustrator-point-exporter) but it seems to only give the x, y coordinates without the curves. I've found a library for processing called [Geomerative](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/geomerative/) but I couldn't figure out how to export the coordinates into specific bezier points that I can import into [bezier()](https://processing.org/reference/bezier_.html)

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Can you provide a sample (simple) exported file, along with a [mcve] showing how you've tried to use the file?

Comment: Check out the Illustrator Scripting Reference. Specifically, the `PathPoint` object, each one is made up of an `anchor` point and a pair of handles (`leftDirection` and `rightDirection`), you should be able to loop through each path, then each pathPoint thus getting all the coordinates you need.

Comment: In an additional step, [export your curve to SVG](https://github.com/Pomax/photoshop-paths-to-SVG), and then use that as your curve data. Or read through that jsx file and adapt it to your use (by putting the data in the clipboard in a way that you can paste as `bezier()` or better, `curveVertex()` data)

Answer (score 0):

You can try export lettering into svg format and then use Processing **loadShape** function to load geometry into varible of type PShape: 
https://processing.org/reference/loadShape_.html